# Get raw key value

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get the raw string of a key value?

```
dictionary = {'key': ['value']}
print(dictionary.get('key'))

>>> ['value']
```

How can I get `'value'` and not `['value']`?

Comment: print(dictionary.get('key'))[0]

Comment: Hint: Read on list index.

Comment: Your dictionary contains one item which is a list with one element. If you don't need the list, use `dictionary = {'key': 'value'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dictionary = {'key': ['value']}
print(dictionary.get('key')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dictionary = {'key': ['value']}
print(dictionary.get('key'))[0]
```

Output:

```
value
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Comment: Your indexing needs to be inside the `print` function

Comment: Yes, but this also produce the same result.

Comment: Only in Python 2 will this work, however, OP tagged python 3.x